# CNTLM issue with intranet (maybe DNS)

Tags: linux, proxy, intranet

On my Linux box I need to use an ISA proxy that requires authentication to reach the internet. I therefore installed CNTLM and configured it to point to the proxy address and listen on port 4321.

I then configured my GNOME distribution to use localhost:4321 as global proxy for HTTP and HTTPS.

The result: I can connect to the internet. I can ping intranet IPs, I do receive name resolution for intranet sites, yet I cannot ping them or open any intranet site in a browser (configured to use the distributions proxy) unless I use the site's IP address.

I tried blocking the intranet IP range in the CNTLM config file without luck.

Comment: Sounds like the ISA proxy isn't resolving internal hostnames.

Comment: Right, but that should be dealt with by adding those sites to the *NoProxy* list of CNTLM? Enabling the authentication proxy is like flipping a switch between "working intranet/broken internet" and "broken intranet/working internet".

Comment: Yup, it should. Can you provide your `cntlm.conf` (minus the secret data), and examples of the intranet URLs.

Comment: It now works... I don't know what changed, but definitely nothing on *my* end. *NoProxy* still points to the intranet IP address range (apart from *localhost* et. al), and I can successfully connect to **both** networks. Maybe this was a caching issue somewhere? I don't like when problems disappear without explanation. :-( Anyways, I very much like your approach and consider awarding the bounty to you, should there be no other awesome answer coming in the next few days. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the ISA proxy is not resolving intranet hostnames correctly. One solution is to write a [proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file which tells the client when and which proxy to use. This doesn't work with CLI programs which use `http_proxy`, but will at least work in browsers.

Save this to a file like `~/proxy.pac` and change to suit your environment. In the GNOME proxy configuration select the "Automatic proxy configuration" option and enter the location of this file as a `file://` URL, e.g. `file:///home/htorque/proxy.pac`.

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    // Strip port number
    host = host.replace(/:\d*/, "");

    // Local destinations
    if (    isPlainHostName(host) ||
            dnsDomainIs(host, ".local") ||
            dnsDomainIs(host, ".mycompany") ||
            shExpMatch(host, "127.*.*.*") ||
            shExpMatch(host, "10.*.*.*") ||
            shExpMatch(host, "192.168.*.*") )
        return "DIRECT";

    // External destinations
    return "PROXY localhost:3128";
}
```

Comment: This worked great for the intranet that I'm on that has its own proxy.pac file which has a large list of proxy bypass destinations. I downloaded the file and simply modified it to point to my local CNTLM proxy. This is on Win2k8 running Chrome.